# Hyperledger Fabric - contract instantiation fails if internet is not available

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, npm-install

I'm trying to create a new network on a computer without internet connection. My case is similar to fabcar example.

The process fails when running `peer chaincode instantiate`.
If internet connection is on everything works fine and smoothly.

The error message I get is:

```
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/fabric-shim failed,
reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
```

As far as I understand (but my understanding here is quite poor) there is some npm install on the peer container during the chaincode instantiation (for chaincode dependencies such as fabric-shim,-network,...?).

Is this correct?

Is there a way of instantiating without leveraging any internet connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a chaincode a new chaincode docker image is built, and then a new container is started based on that image. During the build of that docker image there are npm installs and hence your problem.

You could possibly create your own npm registry using [verdaccio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/verdaccio) or something similar, and then create an `.npmrc` in the folder of your chaincode which can redirect npm install requests to your registry.

(You would also have to pull all the docker images you required into a local docker registry too.)